# How to require a template view in the codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently I use

```
    $data['main_content'] = 'admin/bid/order/view';
    $this->load->view('admin/includes/template', $data);
```

in controller to include the main content. Where the admin/includes/template is just a php that echo the header , main content and footer.

The problem is , in admin/bid/order/view there is a form which use in many other pages , so I would like to extract it , using another php to store it , and include in every other pages.

In the PHP , I use the way of `require_once()`, but how can it achieve in codeigniter? Thanks.

Comment: thanks for remind, in my case I would like to include "a view inside view" , not library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call view in a view if you must know.

in controller

```
$data['main_content'] = 'admin/bid/order/view';
$this->load->view('admin/includes/template', $data);
```

Then in view just do this.

```
$this->load->view('somedirectory/headertemplate');
$this->load->view($main_content);
$this->load->view('somedirectory/footertemplate');
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I would like to include "a view inside view", not "a view". That means there should be another template in the admin/bid/order/view .